I want to remove alternate frames from video strip in blender
I write this code in blender to update the video strip so as to delete alternate frames from it and leave rest of the frames in video sequence editor but it removes first half of the strip instead of alternate frames. Please let me know where I am doing it wrong.
import bpy

# Set the name of your video strip
video_strip_name = "YourStripName"

# Get the video sequence editor
vse = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor

# Find the video strip by name
strip = vse.sequences.get(video_strip_name)

if strip:
    # Create a new list to store the frames to be removed
    frames_to_remove = []

    # Iterate through the frames and identify alternate ones
    for frame in range(strip.frame_final_start, strip.frame_final_end + 1):
    if frame % 2 == 0:
        # Add the frame index to the list
        frames_to_remove.append(frame)

# Remove the identified frames from the beginning
for frame_index in frames_to_remove:
    strip.frame_final_start += 1
else:
    print(f"Video strip '{video_strip_name}' not found.")

print("Alternate frames removed successfully from the beginning!")


Where are you removing frames in your updated code, though? Now you're aggregating every frame to remove in a list, but then you don't actually remove them from the clip after you're done aggregating. Instead, you're moving the strip start by "however many frames you found". So yeah: that'll just bypass the first half of the clip.

Can you please give me the updates what should I do.

You'll probably want https://blender.stackexchange.com first, to get the most experienced eyes on your question. As far as I know, you can't directly remove frames from a strip, since the strip itself is not "video data", it's a metadata marker that only has a start and end.

I post it there too but if I get help from anywhere will be great
